# Pythonic way to find maximum absolute value of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, max, absolute-value

Given the following:

```
lst = [3, 7, -10]
```

I want to find the maximum value according to absolute values. For the above list it will be 10 (`abs(-10) = 10`).

I can do it as follows:

```
max_abs_value = lst[0]
for num in lst:
    if abs(num) > max_abs_value:
        max_abs_value = abs(num)
```

What are better ways of solving this problem?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The built-in `max` takes a key function, you can pass that as `abs`:

```
>>> max([3, 7, -10], key=abs)
-10
```

You can call `abs` again on the result to normalise the result:

```
>>> abs(max([3, 7, -10], key=abs))
10
```

Comment: But the final answer I *think* has to still be the abs answer.

Comment: Perfect, I was looking for a built-in function that returned the actual maximum abs value, I didn't know max func had this key.

Answer (score 13):

```
max(max(a),-min(a))
```

It's the fastest for now, since no intermediate list is created (for 100 000 values):

```
In [200]: %timeit max(max(a),-min(a))
100 loops, best of 3: 8.82 ms per loop

In [201]: %timeit abs(max(a,key=abs))
100 loops, best of 3: 13.8 ms per loop

In [202]: %timeit max(map(abs,a))
100 loops, best of 3: 13.2 ms per loop

In [203]: %timeit max(abs(n) for n in a)
10 loops, best of 3: 19.9 ms per loop

In [204]: %timeit np.abs(a).max()
100 loops, best of 3: 11.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: for small lists (5 numbers) I found `max(map(abs, a))` to be the fastest if you need to return the `abs` value

Answer (score 6):

Use `map`, and just pass `abs` as your function, then call max on that:

```
>>> max(map(abs, [3, 7, -10]))
10
```

Comment: Would've been my first guess (+1)

Comment: What are pros and cons compare to: max([3, 7, -10], key=abs) ?

Comment: The timing analysis does not show much of a difference between the two.

Comment: @trojek You save an extra `abs`, so if you were to use a different evaluation function that would mean less characters and one fewer copy-pasting. Imagine if it was not `abs` but `quicksort_list` for example.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `max()` with a generator comprehension:

```
>>> max(abs(n) for n in [3, 7, -10])
10
```